# Make TypeORM modify only fields that changed

Tags: typeorm

How do I make TypeORM update only the fields that I have modified when saving an object? Here's an example:

```
const user1 = await createTestUser()
const user2 = await User.findOneOrFail({id: user1.id})

user1.email = 'user1@email.com'
await user1.save()

user2.name = 'chris'
await user2.save()

// What is the user's email address?
```

createTestUser() creates the user with an email address like 'test-0wt3d8ypk0hcpng_7adq4v@testing.blahblahblah.com'. user1 changes the email address, user2 changes the name. I would expect this code to change the user's email address in the database to user1@email.com, and the user's name in the database to 'chris'. What actually happens is that when user2.save() is called, it changes the user's email address back to 'test-0wt3d8ypk0hcpng_7adq4v@testing.blahblahblah.com', because that's what the email address was when I retrieved the user row from the database. I want user2.save() to change only the name field.

I know I can use the query builder to update only the field I care about, but it's really annoying to have to go through the code and change all the places where we modify an object like this to avoid a scenario where concurrent saves bite us. Is there a better solution to this that will make TypeORM update only the fields I have changed (user.email in the first example, and user.name in the second)?

Comment: Did you find out about a way of doing this with `repository.save()` I am having the same issue, even with different machines. 

There shouldl be a setting to only update the modified values on save()

Comment: @Fardenz No, we ended up moving away from using .save() wherever we were concerned about concurrent modifications causing bugs like this.

Comment: I see... I found this issue for further reference https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7255

Seems like the objective is to keep `repo.save()` that way... In my case I think I will try to create a proxy which stores the entity into a JSON and compare the changes before saving to limit the query effect.

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now we've decided to change the code to do this instead:

```
    const userRepository = connection.getRepository(User)
    const user1 = await createTestUser()
    const user2 = await User.findOneOrFail({id: user1.id})

    await userRepository.update(user1.id!, {email: 'user1@email.com'})
    await userRepository.update(user2.id!, {name: 'chris'})
```